# How to get URL usage status in Django?

Tags: python, django, url, web, django-urls

Whether it is possible to get a **URL's current usage status or even how many users are currently using a URL.** If it is possible, how can we implement the logic or methodology using Django or python to fetch the data. Hence I am new to web development, kindly please revert back with your queries if my question was not giving any clarity.

I need this methodology to avoid some dynamic functionality which may happen at server end, while the clients are busy using the URL.

Comment: is this of any help https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-tracking/ ?

Comment: Hey thanks @Bilou06.. I think this would be more useful.. This is what i need exactly.